LibreBase DATA ENTRY?
I've loved my Ubuntu system for over 10 yes.
Now that I need to make up a database, I was delighted to find that there's LibreBase to use with it. (Especially as it seems never to let me install any application EXCEPT "in-house".)
Having made several attempts to create a database with it... I find no option anywhere to create an entry, enter data... Nor anything in the manual nor anywhere I can search online that can recognize the topic "DATA ENTRY"...!!??
It it me...? Or do they have a new name for that now? Or... WHAT...!?
Grateful for any suggestions.

I haven't used LibreBase in a long time, but normally you import the data from a flat file or create a form that lets you type it in.

Document Foundation Publication took me all of 10 seconds to find on the web. Also this reference from Ask Libre Office Did you do any research before coming here? Suggest you read [ask] before the next time.

First you need to create a Table, you can enter data into that table then. Usually we use a Form which uses selected columns of a table to present the data or add entries. Forms allow a lot of fine tuning, for examle you can define which already existing data can be edited and which not.

What packages are installed by default vary on Ubuntu product & release of that product, and your question gives no clues as to what Ubuntu you're using. Further some install options offer minimal installs which causes packages on media to not install. Being specific as to what you're actually running will help us better help you.

Deeply grateful for all your timely & thoughtful responses. Will sit down & peruse all this at the1st possible opportunity after the weekend. THANKS ⭐

Thanks to Graham for Document Foundation Publication link. The site is new to me. I found there a LibreBase instruction manual which when searched shows several mentions of "data entry".   Please don't denigrate the value of your own knowledge. I'm glad it was so easy for YOU to find. As for prior research, in Base I clicked help topics. Never heard of anything called "data entry" not even "data". I then used a net search engine, searching "LibreBase" "data entry" & "instructions". Zero relevant results.  Then I came to AskUbuntu. (Cont'd next comment)

(2 of 2) (cont'd from previous) I did first search AskUbuntu before posting, but found no relevant results. I hope you don't think my question too stupidly simple to merit your attention; or resent my coming here to post a question. I fear you undervalue the quality of your knowledge.  LibreBase seems to be structured quite differently from bases I've used in the past. Admittedly, it's been a while, and the programs I'm familiar with are no doubt quite antiquated.
